# Underbraces in Young diagrams

Tags: math-mode

I need to note the number of spaces between two blocks on different rows of a Cherednik diagram.
I have tried

```
 \young(\underbrace{:::}_text{k}\hfill,\hfill)
```

but it doesn't like this and just calls up an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code that is working is as follows

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim, amsmath} % adds environment for commenting out blocks of text & for better verbatim
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage[enableskew]{youngtab}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\begin{document}

\section{Cherednik Diagrams n=2,3}\label{MyFirstSection}

\[ \young(:::\hfill,\hfill)\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  COuld you please provide a complete Minimum Working Example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that shows the issue.  Providing it will help those willing to help you to know what packages you use, and in what context the macro invocation is made.

Comment: What is it meant to look like? You can't have a command like `\underbrace` span multiple columns in a tabular/array environment like that. So this way won't work. But if you tell us what you are trying to do, there might be another way to achieve it.

Comment: I need the underbrace to be between the blocks to illistrate k=1,2,3... gaps, on the same diagram.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility using [`ytableau`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ytableau) and the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library for TikZ (I couln't make this approach work with `youngtab`):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim, amsmath} % adds environment for commenting out blocks of text & for better verbatim
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage[enableskew]{youngtab}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\section{Cherednik Diagrams n=2,3}\label{MyFirstSection}

\ytableausetup{smalltableaux}
\begin{ytableau}[]
 \none & \none  & \tikzmark{starta} \\
\tikzmark{end} \\
\end{ytableau}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=4pt}] 
  ([xshift=5pt]{{pic cs:starta}|-{pic cs:end}}) -- node[below=7pt] {$k$} ([xshift=-5pt]pic cs:end);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

To mark the gap, change the shifts:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim, amsmath} % adds environment for commenting out blocks of text & for better verbatim
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage[enableskew]{youngtab}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\section{Cherednik Diagrams n=2,3}\label{MyFirstSection}

\ytableausetup{smalltableaux}
\begin{ytableau}[]
 \none & \none  & \none & \none & \tikzmark{starta} \\
\tikzmark{end} \\
\end{ytableau}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=4pt}] 
  ([xshift=-5pt]{{pic cs:starta}|-{pic cs:end}}) -- node[below=5pt] {$k$} ([xshift=6pt]pic cs:end);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The document has to be run two or three times for the elements to reach their final positions.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm hoping to be able to have k indicate the number of spaces between the 2 blocks but I think it may end up being something more like this.

Comment: @SarahByers Change the values used for xshift. As soon as I am in front of a computer, I'll update the code.

Comment: @SarahByers Answer updated showing how to mark the gap. In my opinion, the first option (marking not only the number of spaces but also the blocks) is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim, amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage[enableskew]{youngtab}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\begin{document}

\section{Cherednik Diagrams n=2,3}\label{MyFirstSection}

\[ \stackunder[5pt]{\young(:::\hfill,\hfill)}{%
  \stackunder{\makebox[2.15em]{\upbracefill}}{k}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the `2.15em` to other values will change the width of the underbrace.  The vertical separation from the Young diagram and the underbrace has been set to `5pt`.